# Nav brand and nav pills are not on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Even if I'm not a new programmer, Html and Css issue look insolvable for me. The simple reading documentation/specification seems to not be enought as every exemple came with a new brunch of tag and class to demonstrate the use of one of them. I based my code on Bootsrap official demo and documentation but fail this simple task : The nav bar and nav pills are not on the same line.

With the Following code I'm try to achieve a simple nav bar header where the brand is on the left and the menu item on the right.
Menu Item is composed by a text and a photo in a circle under it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <nav>
            <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-start" href="#"><h1>Foo Bar</h1></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
                <li class="justify-content-end" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t0">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="justify-content-end" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t1">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t2">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t3">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t4">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t5">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>


</div>
```

The expected output should be like :

[image]

Comment: Please share jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

Add Class to nav `d-flex justify-content-between`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>Foo Bar</h1></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="justify-content-end" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t0">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="justify-content-end" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t1">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t2">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t3">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t4">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#t5">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <h3>John Doe</h3>
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>


</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/9sce3urb/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code snippet and use flex to align your elements correctly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header navbar navbar-expand flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar">

      <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-start" href="#">
        <h1>Foo Bar</h1>
      </a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto nav nav-pills">
        <li class="justify-content-end" role="presentation">
          <a href="#t0">
            <div class="nav-item">
              <h3>John Doe</h3>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="justify-content-end" role="presentation">
          <a href="#t1">
            <div class="nav-item">
              <h3>John Doe</h3>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" role="presentation">
          <a href="#t2">
            <div class="nav-item">
              <h3>John Doe</h3>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" role="presentation">
          <a href="#t3">
            <div class="nav-item">
              <h3>John Doe</h3>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" role="presentation">
          <a href="#t4">
            <div class="nav-item">
              <h3>John Doe</h3>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" role="presentation">
          <a href="#t5">
            <div class="nav-item">
              <h3>John Doe</h3>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="John" class="img-circle">
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>


  </div>
</body>
```